# Continuous function keeps the convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real random variables and $X_n\to X$ in distribution. If $f$ is a contiuous function, then $f(X_n)\to f(X)$ in distribution.

How do I prove this? Is this correct:

let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^+}$ then 
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_n))=\underbrace{\int f(x_n)P(X_n\geq x)}_{\text{is this correct?}}\xrightarrow{(d)}\int f(x)P(X\geq x)= \mathbb{E}(f(X))$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

It is well known that $X_n\to X$ [in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition) if and only for every bounded and continuous function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have $\mathbb Eg(X_n)\to\mathbb Eg(X)$.

Now observe that $g\circ f$ is bounded and continuous if $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous and $g$ is bounded.