# Invariance under continuous function of "convergence in distribution"

Tags: probability-theory

Let ()∈ℕ be a sequence of real random variables and $X_n\to X$ in distribution. If $s$ is a continuous function, then $s(X_n)→s(X)$ in distribution.

As per hint of [Continuous function keeps the convergence in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915776/continuous-function-keeps-the-convergence-in-distribution), I'm trying to use the fact that convergence in distribution iff vague convergence, but I don't seem to get a result from it.

What I'm thinking is to use $g(x)=1_{s(x)\leq m}$ for $m\in\mathbb{R}$ but this function is not continuous. Where did I do wrong? Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: According to the hint, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{E}\!\left[g(s(X_{n}))\right]\to \mathbb{E}\!\left[g(s(X))\right]$ for every bounded continuous $g$.

Comment: @Ali Yes, that's what I meant. It's vague convergence in other words

Comment: Clearly not what you meant. You have suggested making $g$ specifically an indicator function.

Comment: You're absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does directly follows from the hint, and I didn't need to come up with a particular function $s$.
Indeed, $s(X_n)\to s(X)$ in distribution means that $E(g(s(X_n)))\to E(g(s(X)))$ for every bounded continuous function $g$ but $s\circ g$ is a continuous bounded function.